# What are the differences between High German and other dialects?

Tags: german, language-exchange, germanic-languages

I am going to either Germany or Austria to study German. I have been told there are differences in the German spoken in different regions, and would like to know what these were before choosing the location.

I mostly want to learn German to be able to read academic texts, would this change depending on the region?

Comment: Note that the term *High German* is ambiguous. It can refer to the Souther German dialect group or to the prestige dialect of German. Please [edit] your question to clarify which one you are asking about. Moreover, you may want to specify what kind of academic texts you want to read.

Comment: This question is mostly about the language itself, not about the process of language acquisition. You may ask it on [german.se], but keep in mind that it should be reworded to be more specific.

Comment: okay thanks, I'll ask there